# jsPdf multipage not properly work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I creadted one html page with applying bootstrap css when I export to pdf using pagesplit option pdf doesn't show properly. How to show HTML with high clearity n remove pagesplit problem

```
 $('#cmd').click(function () {
        var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
        var options = {
            pagesplit: true
        };
        pdf.addHTML($('#content')[0],options, function () {

            pdf.output('dataurlnewwindow');
        });
    });
```

here `$('#content')[0]` is main div of HTML which i want to export as pdf

Comment: Please send me working example code.It's  **Urgent**